# el-get waiting for "*bzr branch cedet" to complete

Tags: emacs, autocomplete, bazaar, cedet, el-get

I already have cedet installed on emacs24.  However, whenever I start emacs I get an error that el-get is installing cedet unsuccessfully.  It takes a rather long time and fails somewhere in the make.

Why is el-get downloading cedet that already comes by default, why is it throwing an error, and how can I disable this?

At startup:

```
el-get waiting for "*bzr branch cedet" to complete 
el-get is waiting for "make" to complete
error: el-get: make el-get could not build cedet [make EMACS=/usr/bin/emacs24]
```

Comment: Let me guess, did you try installing `ecb`, `matlab-mode` or `cedet` at any point of time?

Comment: ecb.  It turned out, though I just needed to install texinfo; there was a makeinfo command in the make that was failing.  I'll post that as an answer when the timer lets me.  Is there anything I should be aware of in your suggestions that this is silly?

Comment: Actually the recipes for packages `ecb` and `matlab-mode` declare `cedet` as an requirement. As such whenever you try to install any of these packages, el-get tries to install `cedet` (the `cedet` recipe instruct `el-get` to install the latest version from bzr). `el-get` tries to reinstall any package that failed to install previously at emacs startup (which was again failing) that is why you were seeing this at every emacs startup. In future if you come across such a situation just do `el-get-remove`<the-name-of-offending-package>. You could have used a modified recipe for `ecb`

Comment: @Iqbal Ansari  why don't you write it as an answer instead of a comment, so it can be accepted if it's right

Comment: @Tom, I did not post it as answer since asker had already solved the issue. Anyway I have posted it as an answer now for the benefit of future users. Thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you do `el-get-install`, el-get first tries to install the dependencies
declared by the package. Before installing the package el-get adds the package
to a status file (by default it is in `~/.emacs.d/el-get/.status.el`) and marks
it as a required package and once the package is installed the status is changed
to `installed`. On emacs startup it checks this file to get a list packages that
it has to install and if any package has a status of "required" it is installed
first.

In your particular case, the recipe for the package `ecb` declares `cedet` as a
dependency. So `el-get` tried to install `cedet` first and failed, since the
`cedet` recipe that ships with `el-get` tries to install `cedet` from
source. This step was failing since you did not have `texinfo` installed which
was needed to make `cedet`. As a result `el-get` had cedet marked as
required package and on every startup it was trying to install the it (and failing).

You can do
<kbd>M-x</kbd>`el-get-remove`<kbd>RET</kbd>`name-of-offending-package`<kbd>RET</kbd>,
so that el-get stops trying to install that package. To find out why a particular
package install is failing you can always check the output of build process of
package by switching to the buffer `el-get: build` (I don't remember the name
correctly but it is something similar).

For your particular case you could avoided installing cedet altogether by
instructing `el-get` to install `ecb` from melpa using the following
recipe. Do <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>v</kbd>el-get-sources<kbd>RET</kbd> to read about
recipe syntax

```
(:name ecb
       :description "Emacs Code Browser"
       :type elpa
       :repo ("melpa" . "http://melpa.milkbox.net/packages/"))
```

Add the recipe above to file named `ecb.rcp` in your personal recipe
directory. I store them in `~/.emacs.d/recipes`, the location doesn't matter
though, just ensure that it is in first in the list `el-get-recipe-path` so that
your recipes get precedence over the builtin ones. Something like

```
(add-to-list 'el-get-recipe-path "/path/to/personal/recipes")
```

should be sufficient to ensure that your personal recipes are preferred by `el-get`.